# The affine plane without a point isn't affine $\mathbb{A}_A^2-\{(0,0)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, affine-varieties

I know this is a classic, but there are details which bother me deeply.
I just began studying Scheme Theory and I know just about the basic definitions of schemes (about the first pages of Harris and Eisenbud's *The Geometry of Schemes*).
I wanted to do the following exercice in a more general setting:

Set $A$ a commutative unitary ring, $R=A[X,Y]$, and $\mathbb{A}_A^2=$ Spec($R$) the associated scheme. Now in this situation, the ideal $I=(X,Y)$ may not even be prime, but we still have the closed set
$V(I)\subset \mathbb{A}_A^2$, and we set $U=\mathbb{A}_A^2-V(I)$. Now the objective is to show that this scheme, if it isn't empty, isn't affine. It's empty iff $A=0$.

Now we know that we get a covering of $U$ by the standard opens $D(X)$ and $D(Y)$. Plus we get $D(X)\cap D(Y)=D(XY)$: basic properties of Zariski topology.

Now this induces a diagram of rings of sections via restrictions:

\begin{array}
& & \Gamma(D(X),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2}) &\\
& \nearrow & & \searrow & & \searrow\\
\Gamma(\mathbb{A}_A^2,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2}) & & {}^i\longrightarrow & & \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2}) & \rightarrow & \Gamma(D(XY),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})\\
& \searrow & & \nearrow & & \nearrow\\
&  \Gamma(D(Y),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2}) &\\
\end{array}

(Sorry for  the messy arrows)

Now I get the usual sheaf property over $U=D(X)\cup D(Y)$:
$$0\rightarrow \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})
\rightarrow \Gamma(D(X),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})\times \Gamma(D(Y),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})
\rightrightarrows \Gamma(D(XY),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})$$
is exact. Now we know that for $f\in R$ we get $\Gamma(D(f),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})=R[1/f]$ and the obvious maps between localisations are our restrictions.
So basically I get
$$\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})=
\left\{\left(\frac{P}{X^m},\frac{Q}{Y^n}\right)\bigg|\
P,Q\in R,\
\frac{P}{X^m}\bigg|_{D(XY)}=\frac{Q}{Y^n}\bigg|_{D(XY)}
\right\}$$

Thus by universal construction I get that my arrow $i:\ \Gamma(\mathbb{A}_A^2,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})\rightarrow \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})$ is simply the map that sends
$P\in R$ to $(P_X,P_Y)$ where $P_X$ is just $P$ seen in $R[1/X]$ and idem for $P_Y$.

1. First question: is the description of $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})$ and the morphism $i$ correct?

Here is the fancy part: I know that $X$ and $Y$ are regular in $R$ so my restriction maps are actually ring monomorphisms.
More precisely, I can embed $\Gamma(D(X),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})$,
$\Gamma(D(Y),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})$,
$\Gamma(D(XY),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})$ and 
$\Gamma(\mathbb{A}_A^2,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})$ into $A[X,X^{-1},Y,Y^{-1}]$.
In order to embed $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})$ I take 
$\left(\frac{P}{X^m},\frac{Q}{Y^n}\right)\in
\Gamma(D(XY),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_A^2})$ and I map it to
$\frac{P}{X^m}=\frac{Q}{Y^n}\in A[X,X^{-1},Y,Y^{-1}]$.

Now that all of this is in place I want to show that if $\frac{P}{X^m}=\frac{Q}{Y^n}$ then $m=n=0$ and $P=Q$.

2. Are ther any conditions on the ring $A$ for this to be true?
   I supposed only that $A\neq 0$. Is it enough?

If this is verified then I see that my arrow $i$ is not only injective by the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are regular, but that it is even surjective: $i$ is an
isomorphism.

Now comes the more theoretical part: If $U$ were affine then we would get that by the obvious open immersion map $U\hookrightarrow\mathbb{A}_A^2$ induces the ring ismorphism $i$.

3. This is where it gets tricky: is it by the Yoneda lemma that we can conclude that the immersion $U\hookrightarrow\mathbb{A}_A^2$ is an ismorphism, or by the equivalence of categories **AffSch**$\longrightarrow$**Rings**? Or is it the same? I didn't fully grasp this result.

Thus we are finished since it implies that the canonical inclusion of topological spaces $U\hookrightarrow\mathbb{A}_A^2$ is in fact a homeomorphism which is absurd since it isn't surjective.

I tried to put as much detail as I could in order to be as precise as I can be.
I think it is important to show every detail of ones reasoning when learning something new. I hope someone can shed some light on these questions.

Comment: 1. Not sure which part you are asking about, but it generally seems to be true, 2. This should always hold if $A \neq 0$: When one views $A[X, Y, X^{-1}, Y^{-1}]$ as $A[X, Y, (XY)^{-1}]$, it should be easy to prove using the definition of localization.

Comment: @PavelČoupek For my first question, I wrote a more precise question. I really wanted to see if the way I constructed $\Gamma(U,-)$ and the way I described $i$, were correct. Maybe there are more efficient ways, but this seems the most obvious to me, and the easiest way to manipulate later on.

Comment: I see. Well, I agree with 1. as well. As for 3., I think it works because of the equivalence of affine schemes and rings you mention: The restriction along the inclusion $U \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$ gives you precisely the identity $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^2)=\mathcal{O}(U),$ and applying the $\mathrm{Spec}$ functor gives you back an isomorphism of schemes. But the point is that if $U$ is itself affine, then $(U \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2)\simeq (\mathrm{Spec}\mathcal{O}(U) \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^2))$ and the latter is an isomorphism, so the former is an isomorphism as well.